# Add Layers with Leaflet from Different Spatial Data Frames in R

Tags: r, leaflet-r

Very new to R's Leaflet package and have two spatial data frames.

1) An outline of a city 
2) Its major highways

I wish to show both of these on the same map. I get how to do this with ggmap or tmap. I'm little confused when it comes to Leaflet.

Here is some code that takes public data:

toronto - an outline of the city
all_roads - Toronto's road network

I then view each separately with Leaflet. How do I view multiple layers from different spatial data frames on the same map?

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# Read in Toronto boundaries as a spatial data frame
# WGS84 latitude and longitude
# Data: https://www.toronto.ca/city-government/data-research-maps/open-data/open-data-catalogue/#4a30ca3e-70f0-bf79-1e76-459ebda8458c
toronto <- st_read("/Users.../torontoBoundary_wgs84/citygcs_regional_mun_wgs84.shp")

# Read in street data
# (WGS84 projection)
# https://portal0.cf.opendata.inter.sandbox-toronto.ca/dataset/toronto-centreline-tcl-2/
all_roads <- st_read("/Users.../centreline_wgs84/CENTRELINE_WGS84.shp") 

# Just highways
xway <- filter(all_roads, FCODE_DESC == "Expressway")

map <- leaflet(data = hood_shp, options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 11, maxZoom = 13))
map %>% addPolygons(color = "#aaaaaa", weight = 1.0, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                    opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.7)

highway <- leaflet(data = xway)
highway %>% addPolygons(color = "brown", weight = 1.0, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.7)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simply, dont add the dataset in the `leaflet()` function:

```
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolygons(data=tonto, fillOpacity = 0.7,weight = 1.2, etc....)%>%
    addPolygons(data=xway, fillOpacity = 0.7,weight = 1.2etc....)
```

but you should also consider, perhaps along the line, having the basemap as something very simple such as:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -3.8, lat = 54.8, zoom = 6) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", layerId = "basetile",options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 6))
  })
```

and then you can add layers with observeEvents, buttons, tick boxes etc etc using leafletProxy();

```
leafletProxy("map", data = selectedstuff()) %>%
                        clearShapes() %>%
                        addPolygons(fillColor =  "red",
                                    popup = state_popup,
                                    color = "#BDBDC3",
                                    fillOpacity = 1,
                                    weight = 1)
```

have a google around for the latter, there's loads on the help pages and on this website

[Rstudio leaflet help page for leafletproxy](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html)
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433569/changing-leaflet-map-according-to-input-without-redrawing) (plus many more) might give you more insight into `leafletproxy`